# How is Seiros and Dulb obtained?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

Dulb and Seiros can be used to purchase very good items from the Seiros & Dulb Exchange.

How are these currencies obtained?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get Serios and Dulbs you can sell your bonds.

2★ bonds are worth 2 Serios each and 3★ bonds are worth 10 Serios.

To sell them you have to go to your inventory and select the Bond tab.

Below is a screenshot of the store where you can sell them.

[image: Screen shot of the bond store]

To get Dulbs you need to sell your higher level bonds.
My 4★ bond for Sparkle Princess is worth 50 Serios and 10 Bulbs.

[image: Selling battle princess for dulbs]

Answer (score 1):

Serios and Dulbs can be obtained by:
- Selling 2-star bond (2 serios for each bond)
- Selling 3-star bond (10 serios for each bond)
- Selling 4-star bond (50 serios + 10 dulbs for each bond)